# How does rust create and compare references?

Tags: rust, memory, reference

consider this code, borrowed from [this chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#other-slices) from the official tutorial

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let slice = &a[1..3];
    let slice2 = &b[1..3];
    assert_eq!(slice, &[2, 3]);
    assert_eq!(slice2, &[2, 3]);
    assert_eq!(slice, slice2);
}
```

I would expect the assertions to fail. Why every reference points to the same memory? At first I thought that's because `a` and `b` and the subsequent slices are immutable, so multiple references can address the same memory without problems. But:

```
fn main(){
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut  b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let slice = &a[1..3];
    let slice2 = &mut b[1..3];
    slice2[0] = 2;
    assert_eq!(slice, &[2, 3]);
    assert_eq!(slice2, &[2, 3]);
    assert_eq!(slice, slice2); 
}
```

Again no assertion fails, this time if I change one slice I definitely want two different references, one to the changed slice and one to the immutable one.
However if I replace `slice2[0] = 2;` with `slice2[0] = 6;` (hence actually changing the slice) the assertions fail as expected. The possible causes I can imagine:

- assert_eq! is comparing the actual values not the references. I couldn't verify this since printing the value of a reference right now is above my skill set; the documentation mentions that it uses PartialEq and I don't know how it is implemented for references
- everything is done in a lazy fashion: only when and if one slice actually changes the new memory is allocated and the reference updated (the [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) pattern)

Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: `a == b` is syntax sugar for `a.eq(b)`, `assert_eq!` uses the same methodology, then the correct implementation is looked for by following the auto-dereferencing rules, see [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: thanks @cafce25 , that explains it, if you want points write an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: The implementations for references are [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26B%3E-for-%26A), which I think invokes [this slice-array impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%5BB%5D%3E-for-%5BA%3B%20N%5D), which then invokes the `i32` impl on each element.